# Stop pgAdmin 4 from launching on boot (ubuntu 16.04)

Tags: 16.04, kde, pgadmin

Lately, pgAdmin would automatically launch on boot. I'm using KDE, and there is no entry for pgAdmin in Autostart, nor was there any in `~/.config/autostart` (tho' I'm guessing Autostart uses the file from there anyway).

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Facing the same issue on Ubuntu 18.04 with KDE Plasma 5.12.6. The key problem is that KDE saves desktop session and restores it on reboot. That's why pgAdmin 4 starts automatically if it was running before reboot.

In order to fix this go to **"System Settings"**, select **"Startup and Shutdown"** tab in **"Workspace"** section and then select **"Desktop session"**:

[image: Desktop session]

You will see that **"Restore previous session"** box is enabled in **"On Login"** section there. If you want to exclude pgAdmin 4 only from being restored on login then just type a full path to its executable in **"Applications to be excluded from sessions"**:

```
/usr/bin/pgAdmin4
```

You can detect a path by running:

```
which pgAdmin4
```

If you don't want to save desktop session related data then another simple solution is to tick **"Start with an empty session"** box.

After that click **"Apply"** button and reboot the system. Now pgAdmin 4 will start and open a browser only when you make it explicitly.

Comment: wohoo same issue on plasma, always learning about a new plasma settings panel : :' )

Answer (score 2):

Turns out it was due to `pgadmin4` was still running in the background, so it would launch itself again on next logins. I just killed the process with old school `pkill -f pgAdmin4` and it would no longer automatically launch itself on next logins. There's no need to stop `postgresql` service.

**EDIT 26/12/2018:** I've instead marked @Ezze's answer as the solution as that's indeed a better way to do it in my case.

Comment: It was `pkill -f pgAdmin4` for me instead of `pkill -f pgadmin4`. I confirm it works but next time you run pgAdmin you have to kill it again if you don't want to start it automatically on next boot.

Answer (score 0):

You can disable startup services using:

```
sudo systemctl stop postgresql
sudo systemctl disable postgresql
```

Comment: It would stop postgresql server from starting on boot, but it wouldn't stop pgadmin (even if there'd be no online servers that could be accessed from it). Either way, I don't mind the sql server starting on boot, in fact I desired that, I just don't want pgadmin in particular to do so.

Comment: Yeah, could someone vote this answer down? It's not correct given the question.

Comment: postgresql is not pgadmin, You are correctly disabling postgresql but it is not the answare as TechJohn said. 
nb: same asware here: https://ubuntu.forumming.com/question/8741/stop-pgadmin-4-from-launching-on-boot-ubuntu-16-04
as ezze pointed Pgadmin4 is not a service, but session stuff...
(by the way...My opinion is that a service would be better...)